# Open Modal Box from link in SPGridView using JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint, hyperlink, spgridview

I have a SPGridView in SharePoint 2010 Foundation containing announcements from subsites. I have only one column, a HyperLinkField that displays the title of the announcement and links to the dispform of the item.

The data is collected using a SPDataSiteQuery.

What I want is the link to run a JavaScript, added on the page with a Content Editor Web Part, that will open a Modal Box and in it display the dispform.

My code currently looks like below and succentsfully opens the dispform in the same window but I now want it to call the JavaScript.

```
HyperLinkField hyperFieldTask = new HyperLinkField();
            hyperFieldTask.HeaderText = "News";
            hyperFieldTask.DataTextField = "Title";

            string[] itemUrl = { "FileDirRef" };
            hyperFieldTask.DataNavigateUrlFields = itemUrl;
            hyperFieldTask.DataNavigateUrlFormatString = "";
            hyperFieldTask.SortExpression = "Title";

            this.grid.Columns.Add(hyperFieldTask);
```

I have tried several solutions but all I get is an inactive link.

```
hyperFieldTask.DataNavigateUrlFormatString = "JavaScript:ShowDialog('url')";

hyperFieldTask.DataNavigateUrlFields = "JavaScript:ShowDialog('url')";
```

Nothing I do seems to work.

Have I missed something obvious?

Thanks for helping.

EDIT:

I tried using NavigateUrl and it does indeed call the JavaScript.

```
hyperFieldNews.NavigateUrl = "javascript:ShowDialog('http://www.google.com', '600')";
```

The next step is now to instead of using www.google.com as url I want to use the value of "FileDirRef".

Answer (score 0):

add the following JavaScript function:

`<script type="text/javascript">
     function ModalPopup(url, title) {
         var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
         options.url = url;
         options.title = title;
         options.dialogReturnValueCallback = function () {
             SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
         };
         SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
     }
</script>`

now you can create a link and call the function:

`HyperLink hyper1 = new HyperLink();
string popUpPageUrl = "javascript:ModalPopup('" + url + "','Display Item')";
hyper1.NavigateUrl = popUpPageUrl;
hyper1.Text = "News";`